# How can I set the System.Web.Optimization bundler to correctly transform ISO unicode

Tags: css, asp.net, unicode, system.web.optimization

My CSS:

```
    #site-heading li:after {
        content: '\2002\2022\2002';
    }
```

Gets transformed to:

```
#site-heading li:after{content:'???'}
```

during the bundling process and I can't figured out how to get it so the content remains a space, bullet, space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, you don't set anything within System.Web.Optimization.

Instead make sure the css file in the bundle is encoded as UTF-8.  The @charset "utf-8"; declaration at the top of the file is not enough.  The file has to physically be encoded.  Pasting a UTF-8 symbol directly in Visual Studio, will casue Visual Studio to question you if you want to save as UTF-8 upon saving the file.  Alternatively, using something like Notepad++, one can convert the encoding format from the menu (Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8), then save.

```
    #site-heading li:after {
        content: ' • ';
    }
```

This content is then parsed and converted as intended when bundled/minified.